# is_prime function using filter abstract function

Tags: python, generator, primes

I am trying to use 'filter' the abstract function to solve is_prime problem. 
I think this is logical works, But the result always be False. and when I add 'print (lon)', tring to find out the problem. It types something I don't understand.

I tried the recursive way, it works.

```py
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    lon = filter (lambda x: n % x == 0, list(range (2, n)))
    if lon == []:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

the result always be False.

by adding

```
print(lon)
```

running

```
is_prime(7)
```

result is

```
<filter object at 0x039456D0>
False
```

Comment: you need to make the result of filter a list: `list(filter (lambda x: n % x == 0, list(range (2, n))))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve your immediate problem, you need to consider types. Because `filter(…)` returns a generator object of type `filter`, it can never be equal to `[]` – an object of type `list`. So you could just do `if list(lon) == []:` or, even better, `if not any(lon):` and call it a day, the function would work the way you wanted.

A few tips though:

- comparing to `[]` is not very Pythonic, an empty list is considered `False` anyway
- it'd be best to ditch `if` and `else`, and instead `return not any(lon)`
- however, if you just want to check most efficiently if a given number is prime, you might want to reconsider your approach – checking `n-2` numbers is not a good idea; consider for example that:

  - only one prime factor can be greater than `sqrt(n)` and non–primes by definition have more than that one factor, so you only need to check up to `sqrt(n)`
  - no even number is prime, so you only need to check every other number
- and for anything more professional use a scientifically proven extremely optimized algorithm, such as [the Miller–Rabin primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miller%E2%80%93Rabin_primality_test) (refer to section "Deterministic variants" for implementation guidance)

Answer (score 0):

A filter object will never be == to a list so you will always get false. 
Instead, check if the filter is empty.

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    lon = filter (lambda x: n % x == 0, list(range (2, n)))
    try:
        min(lon)
    except ValueError:
        return True
    return False
```

Edit: an even cleaner way

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n == 2:
        return True
    lon = filter (lambda x: n % x == 0, list(range (2, n)))
    if not any(lon):
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: @yifanYang No Problem! I ran into the same types of issues when I first came to python once upon a time.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your current use of `filter` is the wrong approach generator-wise.  By letting `filter` generate a *complete* result so you can measure it's length, you've lost any advantage of using a generator!

Instead consider a generator approach where if at any step in the generation we detect a remainderless division, the whole generation chain stops and we return `False`:

```
def is_prime(n):
    if n <= 2 or n % 2 == 0:
        return n == 2

    return not any(filter(lambda x: n % x == 0, range(3, int(n ** 0.5) + 1, 2)))
```

Given that `filter`, `any` and `range` are all lazy, we only complete generation in the case of a prime.  You don't care 15 has multiple prime divisors, but your original `filter` approach finds them both!  The above approach should resolve the *"is it a prime"* question as soon as it finds its first divisor, and not look further.

Comment: Thanks! your code is much more efficient. THANK YOU!